# Restricted set of nested fields in a django REST framework ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Consider the following serializer

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'account')
        depth = 1
```

The field `account` refers to a `ForeignKey` in `MyModel` and I want to expose some of the `Account` fields with this serializer but not all of them.

How do I specify that only `account.name` and `account.email` should be serialized?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating your own serializer to use as the nested serializer.

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('name', 'email', )
```

You are better off with creating specialized serializers instead of relying on Django REST Framework to create them for you. By default, serializers that are automatically created contain *all* fields defined on the model.

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    account = AccountSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'account', )
```

You can find out more about nested serializers in the [Django REST Framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#nested-relationships).

Comment: Got it. It would be great to extend `ModelSerializer` to include that feature in Django REST framework though.

Comment: You would have to override how the [nested serializer is generated](http://git.io/ckBmww), it'd end up being far more work that just creating a second (or third, or fourth...) serializer.